# This webpage has a redirect loop and not geting user ID

Tags: php, facebook

I am using the following script of code and the page get stuck to infinite loop as it does not getting user id. Please help me.

```
<?php
include_once("facebook.php");

# Creating the facebook object  
$facebook = new Facebook(array(  
    'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',  
    'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',  
    'cookie' => true  
));  

$user = $facebook->getUser(); 
if($user) { 
    try{  
        $user = $facebook->api('/me');  
    } catch (Exception $e){}  
    if(!empty($user)){  
        print_r($user); 
    } 
    else { 
        die("There was an error.");  
    }  
} 
else {  
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>$fbPermissions,'redirect_uri'=>'http://www.mysit.com.com/script/check.php'));
    header("Location: ".$login_url);  
}
?>
```

Comment: print the exception and see what happens.. in side th catch block

Comment: `else { 
      die("There was an error.");  
         }  
     } `delete one `}`

Comment: @FaceOfJock one of the `}` goes to the `if($user)`

Comment: @Class yes thanks ,indentation problem

Comment: maybe they aren't logged in. [getUser](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getUser/)

Comment: actual problem is here in this piece of code,   $user = $facebook->getUser(); 
    if($user) { 
      try{  
         $user = $facebook->api('/me');  
       } catch (Exception $e){}  
    else {  
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>$fbPermissions,'redirect_uri'=>'http://www.mysit.com.com/script/check.php'));
    header("Location: ".$login_url);  
}

Comment: i have deleted the rest part in the code but the actual problem is its not getting inside if portion and always execute else portion, mean not getting userid that y its get stuck

Comment: @ Anto Vinisn, control not getting inside if portion

Comment: its no logining that y its return zero all tym please help me

Comment: _“error=CSRF state token does not match one provided”_ – that usually hints to sessions not working correctly (since the FB SDK stores the `state` parameter into the session). So go and check if the session id gets passed correctly between calls, or if you get a new one every time.

Answer (score 0):

Because of this function its going in infinite redirect loop

```
header("Location: ".$login_url);
```

Remove the above line from your code and add this line insted;

```
echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
```

This link will take you to the page where you can login to the app.

`getLoginUrl()` generates a new token. If your user is already logged in (with `$user_id = $facebook->getUser()`), you'll end up with 2 tokens.

Don't ask for the $loginUrl if the user is authenticated already.

Comment: thanks, its just escape me out from infinite loop, but still it provide me this error=CSRF state token does not match one provided.

Comment: $user_id = $facebook->getUser(); 
 echo "idd=".$user_id;
if($user_id) { 
echo "idd=".$user;
 $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

   try{  
    $user = $facebook->api('/me');  
   } catch (Exception $e){} 
  } 
    
 else {  
 
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>$fbPermissions,'redirect_uri'=>'http://www.maunsellparts.com/script/check.php'));
    echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
 exit();
       }

Comment: still have the same problem